Convert Datetime to another culture in SQL & C#
I used this code to convert date to "Arabic" culture
select FORMAT(CAST('2024-06-03' AS DATE), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 'ar-SA')

but the result is wrong date. this date '2024-06-03' actually is '1445/11/25' in Arabic but this is '1445/11/26' what is I got.
I found a SQL function at Github but the problem was same and this problem is bigger than I think because I test it in C# console with this code
DateTime.Parse("2024-06-03").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA"))

and saw the wrong converted date here again.
I have no idea how I can fix it, can anybody help me at this situation?
I used this types of casting
format(PARSE('[date]' as date), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'ar-SA')
format(CAST('[date]' as date), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'ar-SA')
format(CONVERT(DATE, '[date]'), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'ar-SA')


Google don't agree with you

Everything my Google-Fu leads me to disagrees and states that 2024-06-03 is 26-11-1445; this appears, therefore, like you're saying there is a bug with C++, C#, and other languages.

(Oddly, however, SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'20240603'),131); returns '27/11/1445')

@ThomA it says on the tin that: 5 Hijri is a calendar system with several variations. SQL Server uses the Kuwaiti algorithm. so perhaps that's what OP is looking for? Some other algo

Yeah, it's more that I would expect CONVERT and FORMAT to return the same value, @siggemannen  (though I appreciate that FORMAT is a CLR function "under the hood").

tip: don't store dates as strings, especially in SQL databases; then there is no conversion to do; store them in their appropriate typed - date, datetime (SQL) DateOnly, DateTime, etc

@MarcGravell you can't easily store Hijri dates in a date and time data type in SQL Server; they all use the Gregorian calendar.

There is some info in C# ref it says some adjustment is going on depending on things so perhaps it all depends on the settings of the system

@ThomA all of the date types are just integers with a specific offset and frequency; heck, if you're upset by the in-the-box ones, just store an integer and do the offset/frequency math yourself; just: anything that involves string formatting/parsing is always going to be significantly more complex, troublesome and computationally expensive than: integer math on unix time, etc; maybe using NodaTime etc on the UI side

They are binary values (in SQL Server), not integers, @MarcGravell . The old date and time ((small)datetime)  allowed for implicit conversion from/to numerical values, but the new ones don't. Even then, (small)datetime was closer to a numeric, as 0.5 represented 12 hours.

@ThomA I guess the point was to "not use string". What exactly to use instead will always depend on DBMS and the version thereof.

-- Converting Gregorian date to Hijri date

DECLARE @gregorianDate DATE = '2024-06-03';
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @gregorianDate, 111) AS GregorianDate,
 -- Format: yyyy/mm/dd
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @gregorianDate, 130) AS HijriDate;
 -- Hijri format: dd MMM yyyy


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
